# Understanding on Artin's proof of the generalised associative law for associative binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, associativity

On the 2nd edition of Artin's *Algebra*, the writer uses *proposition 2.1.4* to imply that generalised associative law works for associative binary operation:

> **Proposition 2.1.4** Let an associative law of composition be given on a set $S$. There is a unique way to define, for every integer $n$, a product of $n$ elements $a_1...a_n$ of $S$, denoted temporarily by $[a_1...a_n]$, with the following properties:

> **(i)** The product $[a_1]$ of one element is the element itself.

> **(ii)** The product $[a_1a_2]$ of two elements is given by the law of composition.

> **(iii)** For any integer $i$ in the range $1\le i<n$, $[a_1...a_n]=[a_1...a_i][a_{i+1}...a_n]$

I have no problem understanding the proof of this proposition, but I would like to ask how this proposition implies the generalised associative law.

---

My understanding:

Artin's notation $[a_1...a_n]$ should be equivalent to a function $f_n(a_1,...,a_n):S^n\to S$.

Let $b(a_1,...,a_n)$ denotes a product of $a_1...a_n$ with some well-defined bracketing.

One could observe that, for any $b(a_1,...,a_n)$, we have $f_n(a_1,...,a_n)=b(a_1,...,a_n)$ by **(i)** and **(iii)**. So, any well-defined bracketing on a product evaluates to the same value (i.e generalised associative law).

---

May I ask, if my understanding is correct, why would we even need to prove for uniqueness? We can just show the existence of $f_1$, then show the existence of $f_n$ for $n>1$ by defining $f_n$ recursively using $f_1$ (for each $n$ check **(i)** **(ii)** **(iii)** using induction). Once we have $f_i$ for all $1\le i\le n$, we could check that $f_n(a_1,...,a_n)=b(a_1,...,a_n)$ for any two bracketings.

If my understanding is incorrect, may I ask how Proposition 2.1.4 implies generalised associative law?

Comment: What do you think the *generalized associative law* is?

Comment: @TedShifrin Bracketing is insignificant for a product of any finite number of elements (the result of the product is independent to the order of computation?)?

Comment: Not the order of computation. But of the *grouping* of the elements. So write down the case of three elements. (c) tells you that $[a_1 a_2 a_3] = a_1[a_2 a_3] = [a_1 a_2]a_3$, so the product of three doesn't depend on the grouping.

Comment: @J-A-S What do you mean by "a product of any finite number of elements"? What do you mean by "bracketing is insignificant"? If there is a different theorem that deserves to be called the "generalized associative law", that different theorem would need to be stated precisely.

Comment: @littleO I think here we are trying to prove that a product with bracketing of any (meaningful) fashion evaluates to the same value (so that a product without bracketing can be defined as the same product with any bracketing). Honestly I haven't encountered "generalized associative law" in other meaning, sorry if the use of generalized associative law here caused inaccuracy

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your reply, but I still don't quite get why it is necessary to care about uniqueness in proposition 2.1.4?

Comment: Without uniqueness the arbitrary product will not be well-defined. That's the whole point!

Comment: @TedShifrin I think we can treat the arbitrary product $[a_1...a_n]$ as a function $f_n(a_1,...,a_n)$. Define $f_1(a)=a$ and recursively $f_n(a_1,...,a_n)=f_{n-1}(a_1,...,a_{n-1})f_1(a_n)$. This particular set of functions we defined possess properties (i) (ii) and (iii), so properties (i) and (iii) show that any well-defined bracketing of $a_1...a_n$ is equal to $f_n(a_1,...,a_n)$. If this argument is correct, then we only need to work with one particular set of functions and whether there are other functions possess the same properties seems irrelevant?

Comment: That means that if you are presented with the product $f_2(a,b)f_2(c,d)$, you'll have no way to know if $(ab)(cd) = a(bc)d$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your example. Sorry if I get your idea wrong, do you mean we want to show $(ab)(cd)=a(bc)d$? With $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ being defined as in my previous comment, by property (iii) and (i) we have $f_4(a,b,c,d)=f_2(ab)f_2(cd)=(f_1(a)f_1(b))(f_1(c)f_1(d))=(ab)(cd)$ and $f_4(a,b,c,d)=f_1(a)f_3(b,c,d)=f_1(a)(f_2(b,c)f_1(d))=f_1(a)((f_1(b)f_1(c))f_1(d))=a(bc)d$, hence $(ab)(cd)=a(bc)d$

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh by the way I don't think $a(bc)d$ is a well-defined bracketing (I showed $(ab)(cd)=a((bc)d)$ )

Comment: @TedShifrin I mean, if I'm presented with $f_2(a,b)f_2(c,d)$, I know it's $(ab)(cd)$. And I know $f_4(a,b,c,d)=f_2(a,b)f_2(c,d)$, so I can start from $f_4(a,b,c,d)$ to get some other bracketing and it shows that such bracketing is the same as $(ab)(cd)$. Could you please clarify what you meant by $a(bc)d$ there?

Answer (score 0):

Let p(a_1,...,a_n) be any product of n elements in S. We can use strong induction to prove that p(a_1,...,a_n) = [a_1...a_n] as follows.  Suppose this is true for all k < n. Now p(a_1, ..., a_n) = p'(a_1,...,a_k) p"(a_(k+1),...,a_n) for some products p' on k elements and p" on n-k elements. By the strong inductive hypothesis, p' and p" are identical to the product defined in Proposition 2.1.4, and so the rhs is equal to [a_1...a_k] [a_(k+1)...a_n] which, by (iii) is equal to [a_1...a_n]